# How to check both objects value are same or not using lodash

Tags: javascript, object, lodash

I am having two objects like below

Object 1:

```
{
  "action": "Accept",
  "destination_port": "",
  "destination_subnet": "192.168.1.2",
  "id": "59-1601004430291",
  "lan_interface": "eth0",
  "order": 2,
  "protocol": "any",
  "source_port": "",
  "source_subnet": "192.168.0.0/32",
  "wan_interface": "wlan0"
}
```

Object 2:

```
{
  "action": "Accept",
  "destination_port": "",
  "destination_subnet": "0.0.0.0",
  "lan_interface": "eth0",
  "protocol": "tcp",
  "source_port": "",
  "source_subnet": "198.168.43.0",
  "wan_interface": "wlan0"
}
```

I would like to compare both objects and check if the values are the same or not. But the object1 might have some properties which are not available in object2.

I have done an implementation like below

```
const isDuplicate = (o1, o2) => {
  if (
     o1.action === o2.action &&
     o1.destination_port === o2.destination_port &&
     o1.destination_subnet === o2.destination_subnet &&
     o1.lan_interface === o2.lan_interface &&
     o1.protocol === o2.protocol &&
     o1.source_port === o2.source_port &&
     o1.source_subnet === o2.source_subnet &&
     o1.wan_interface === o2.wan_interface
    ) {
        return true;
      } else {
        return false;
      }
  };
```

I would like to know whether it can be even simplified with lodash

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/23048303/5605822

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `_.isEqual()` to compare the subset of both items (via `_.pick()`) that you want to check:

```js
const isDuplicate = (...objs) => _.isEqual(...objs.map(o => _.pick(
  o,
  ['action', 'destination_port', 'destination_subnet', 'lan_interface', 'protocol', 'source_port', 'source_subnet', 'wan_interface'],
)))

const obj1 = {"action":"Accept","destination_port":"","destination_subnet":"192.168.1.2","id":"59-1601004430291","lan_interface":"eth0","order":2,"protocol":"any","source_port":"","source_subnet":"192.168.0.0/32","wan_interface":"wlan0"}

const obj2 = {"action":"Accept","destination_port":"","destination_subnet":"0.0.0.0","lan_interface":"eth0","protocol":"tcp","source_port":"","source_subnet":"198.168.43.0","wan_interface":"wlan0"}

const result = isDuplicate(obj1, obj2)

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.20/lodash.min.js" integrity="sha512-90vH1Z83AJY9DmlWa8WkjkV79yfS2n2Oxhsi2dZbIv0nC4E6m5AbH8Nh156kkM7JePmqD6tcZsfad1ueoaovww==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

If the 2nd object is always a subset of the 1st, you can use `_.isMatch()` instead, but that will only check properties that exist on `obj2`:

```js
const obj1 = {"action":"Accept","destination_port":"","destination_subnet":"192.168.1.2","id":"59-1601004430291","lan_interface":"eth0","order":2,"protocol":"any","source_port":"","source_subnet":"192.168.0.0/32","wan_interface":"wlan0"}

const obj2 = {"action":"Accept","destination_port":""}

const result = _.isMatch(obj1, obj2)

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.20/lodash.min.js" integrity="sha512-90vH1Z83AJY9DmlWa8WkjkV79yfS2n2Oxhsi2dZbIv0nC4E6m5AbH8Nh156kkM7JePmqD6tcZsfad1ueoaovww==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**: I get wrong your question sorry try again.

```js
let obj1 = {
  "action": "Accept",
  "destination_port": "",
  "destination_subnet": "192.168.1.2",
  "id": "59-1601004430291",
  "lan_interface": "eth0",
  "order": 2,
  "protocol": "any",
  "source_port": "",
  "source_subnet": "192.168.0.0/32",
  "wan_interface": "wlan0"
};

let obj2 = {
  "action": "Accept",
  "destination_port": "",
  "destination_subnet": "0.0.0.0",
  "lan_interface": "eth0",
  "protocol": "tcp",
  "source_port": "",
  "source_subnet": "198.168.43.0",
  "wan_interface": "wlan0"
};

let obj3 = {
  "action": "Accept",
  "destination_port": ""
};
let obj4 = {
  "action": "Accept",
  "destination_port": ""
};


function comp(obj1, obj2) {
  return JSON.stringify(obj1) === JSON.stringify(obj2)
}

console.log(comp(obj1, obj2));
console.log(comp(obj3, obj4));
```

Comment: Have you ran this code and checked the result? It's not working

Comment: check my comment again and see?

Comment: @Tasos again sorry. I hope that's what you are looking for

Comment: This is working now, but not for objects that may have more properties between them

Comment: Imma looking for better answer. **Edit**: Looks like you found your answer.

Comment: @BerkEge No problem :) you gave it a try thanks for your time