# How to check if an object contains another object like

Tags: javascript, object, javascript-objects

How to check if an object contains another object like

```
const LHS = {
a : "Something a",
b : "Something b",
c : { a : "Something a"}
}

let RHS = {
a : "Something a",
c : { a : "Something a"}
}

// How to write a function contains which replicates this behaviour

contains(LHS, RHS) // should return true

 RHS = {
a : "Something a",
c : { a : "Something a"},
d : "Something d"
}

contians(LHS, RHS) // Should return false
```

I have abosulety no Idea how to do that. If you know some external libaries that does this please share it.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want to check if all the key/value pairs within one object are also contained within another object? That's very similar to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23045652/10221765), from which I found the easiest method to check is to use [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23045777/10221765) combined with `isEqual`. Yes, bringing in libraries/modules is a hassle, but regardless, it's about as optimized as this operation could be.

```js
const LHS = {
  a: "Something a",
  b: "Something b",
  c: {
    a: "Something a"
  }
}

let RHS = {
  a: "Something a",
  c: {
    a: "Something a"
  }
}

both = _.merge(_.cloneDeep(LHS), RHS);

console.log(_.isEqual(both, LHS));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.20/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

This code will duplicate the first object (`LHS`) and merge that with the second (`RHS`) - those should be identical if all key/value pairs in `RHS` are also in `LHS`.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JBDouble05/z0gfxsq7/1/)